# Sending mail with SendGrid v3 C# just hangs

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I've upgraded from v2 to v3 and (C# implementation) of SendGrid. I can get it to send mail, but it just hangs in the code after doing so on the **last line**:

```
dynamic sendGridAPIClient = new SendGridAPIClient(SendGridApi);

Email from = new Email(EmailAddress, EmailName);
Email to = new Email(EmailAddress, EmailName);
Content content = new Content("text/html", message);
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

dynamic response = sendGridAPIClient.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
```

It's annoying because it goes into a black hole with that function and you can't debug it unlike v2 which worked just fine.

Comment: Somebody reported this as a bug on their Github page. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/235

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `await`, try this instead:

`var response = sendGridAPIClient.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get())
    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Note that a `response.StatusCode` of `OK (200)`, rather counter-intuitively, means SendGrid have thrown the mail message into the void.

You want a `StatusCode` of `Accepted (202)`, which means it's been queued for delivery.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Asynchronous Call, so try this:

```
dynamic response = await sendGridAPIClient.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
```